# How to change the color of the Reorder icon in editable List?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have an editable List of which items can be re-ordered. I want to change the Reorder color. How to do that?

```
struct DummyList: View {
    @State private var items = ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3"]
    @State private var editMode = EditMode.active
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                Text(item)
            }
            .onMove(perform: move)
        }
        .toolbar {
            EditButton()
        }
        .environment(\.editMode, $editMode)
    }

    func move(from source: IndexSet, to destination: Int) {
        items.move(fromOffsets: source, toOffset: destination)
    }
}
```

[image: Reorder image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can change the foreground color of the re-order button. However, you can at least change the background behind it, using `listRowBackground`:

```swift
ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
    Text(item)
}
.onMove(perform: move)
.listRowBackground(
    Color(UIColor.secondarySystemGroupedBackground)
        .overlay(alignment: .trailing) {
            Color.orange
                .frame(width: 44)
                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 6))
                .padding(.vertical, 4)
                .padding(.trailing, 10)
        }
)
```

It turns out that the button is shown using a semi-transparent shade of gray, so the background adds a tint effect to the button itself:

[image: Screenshot]

Setting a shape behind the button in this way is a bit like what you see when button shapes is turned on in the accessibility settings. However, it won't conflict, because it seems the re-order button does not change its appearance when the setting is turned on.

Of course, this kind of effect may be impacted by a design change in a future version of iOS. So you might want to restrict its use to versions that you have tested.

Comment: That is a great workaround. I'll give it a try, thank a bunch!

Comment: I already have a listRowBackground(.black) as the interface is all black. Is it possible to add a second overlay on top ?

Comment: @wanted So you already have an overlay over the list row background? In any case, yes, you can add as many overlays as you like.